# How do I load a module at boot time?

Tags: boot, linux, driver, modules

As stated in [Why is my Audio (Sound) Output not working?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-my-audio-sound-output-not-working), to initialise the sound driver, you must run `sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835` every time you want to output sound.

How do I get this to run on boot? (i.e. before logging in and without any input)

Comment: This is another question that could be regarded off-topic. It may be better suited to [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Although a decent question, I'm going to VTC. This is a very generic Linux problem. What you be more helpful is a merge of your answer into the [audio question mentioned](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-my-audio-sound-output-not-working).

Comment: @Jivings: Just because it's on-topic on [unix.se] doesn't make it off-topic for [RaspberryPi.SE], does it?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: I think that there's too much of an overlap in this particular question. Nothing about this question makes it specific for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Wouldn't the decision at http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24/raspberry-pi-itself-vs-specific-os-issues mean that this question is fine here?

Comment: @GrahamWager: Yes, and that's why the question wasn't closed.

Comment: @Jivings Thanks, just wanted to clear that up for any future visitors as the comments were pointing towards closing the question. Maybe all the comments should be deleted instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356224/how-to-load-a-custom-module-at-the-boot-time-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Modprobe on Boot - Debian

To answer the specific question about `sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835`, add the module to `/etc/modules` and reboot. (You will need to be `root` to do this.)

## Starting services - Debian

Debian using initscripts to initialise the system, and you can use them to run arbitrary commands. You need to install a script similar to the following in `/etc/init.d`.

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/blah
#

# Some things that run always
touch /var/lock/blah

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting script blah "
    echo "Could do more here"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping script blah"
    echo "Could do more here"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/blah {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

You should ensure it is runnable and owned by root.

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/blah
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/blah
```

Then you need to register it to run at startup.

```
sudo update-rc.d blah defaults
```

## References

- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28

Comment: Neither of these things are unique to Debian. Also, init scripts are not what you should be using to load modules. Only the first section is relevant to the question.

Comment: Neither of them will work on Arch, not sure about QtonPi.

Comment: Of course they will.

Comment: Oh... why is your Arch answer different then?

Comment: Because Arch defines a handy abstraction for startup events.

Answer (score 25):

Loading modules at boot is a little different to running startup commands.

### In Debian:

Add the module name as a new line in `/etc/modules`

### In Arch Linux:

Add the module name to the module array in `/etc/rc.conf`, the line should look like this:

```
modules=(snd_bcm2835)
```

Or for the new systemd configuration:

```
echo "snd_bcm2835" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules-load.d/snd_bcm2835.conf
```

Comment: I added `snd_bcm2835` to the `/etc/modules` file on my Xbian but that created a loop at boot time. this seems not be allowed when starting OSMC

Comment: @rubo77 Interesting! Did you get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe it was a coincident. The whole installation seems a bit broken by now...

Answer (score 3):

There are loads of ways of running a command at start-up in Linux but my favoured approach is to create an initialisation script in `/etc/init.d` and register it using `update-rc.d`.  This way the application is started and stopped automatically when the system boots / shutdowns.

See [this post](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html) for a set of instructions on how to create one on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Beta! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: How would you do it through `systemd` or other systems?

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach would be to add the setup command to /etc/rc.local where it would be initialised at the end of boot, before you are asked to login.