# Create Startup Sound

Tags: raspbian, boot, audio

I know that this question has already been answered, but [the method described here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/running-headless-how-do-i-create-a-boot-sound)
is actually not working for me... o.O
I read in some other forums that a different formatting is required, but I don't know which... If anyone could help me with this...
I am running Raspbian's latest release as of 28/11/2014
Cheers

Comment: You should include a link to the other question, what do you mean by not working, what do the logs say if anything, is there any message in dmesg?

Comment: Sorry, the link to the other question is actually the word "here"... It's my fault, I didn't make it very clear...

Comment: When using the solution described in the link, as soon as i create the file and add the script in Nano, exit and save I get `chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/init.d/start-sound': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Ok, in the end I managed to find the rest of the script by using the formatting of another startup-script. (`##BEGIN INIT INFO` part was actually missing). I am going to share the script here in some time, so everybody who is still trying to figure out how to create a Startup Sound can use it...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a startup sound using mplayer and a mp3 file.

Here is what you need:

1. Install mplayer

   > sudo apt-get install mplayer
2. Make sound directory in /etc

   > sudo mkdir /etc/sound
3. Upload the sound file as mp3 to the sound directory

   > sudo mv /tmp/soundfile.mp3    /etc/sound/sample.mp3
4. Copy and paste below line on command promp

   > sudo echo "mplayer /etc/sound/sample.mp3" >> /etc/rc.local

make sure to upload your mp3 file to your raspberry pi in /tmp/ directory

Comment: The file `rc.local` is actually containing something about my IP-Adress... I am not familiar with scripting, would you be able to show me what exactly to add in that file?

Comment: @BlackWhiteX I have updated my answer by formatting code and making it clear.

Comment: using your solution, when I type in `sudo echo "mplayer /etc/sound/sample.mp3" >> /etc/rc.local` I get `-bash: /etc/rc.local: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `aplay` use `omxplayer` which can read MP3, AAC, WAVE and a few others.

```
# /etc/init.d/start-sound

echo "Playing startup sound"
omxplayer /path/to/file.mp3 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

omxplayer is pre installed with the latest (for a while now) and also you can do the same to play video to a selected output device.

If you get permission error try putting `sudo` in front of omxplayer

Answer (score 0):

Add the command to play the sound at the end of `/etc/rc.local`