# Need a beginner test program written in Python for audio (sound) output

Tags: raspbian, python, audio

I would like to find a  beginner test program for audio in Python. A program that can  play sounds (.wav files or whatever). From the code, I can then begin to learn how to work with audio output.

Specifically, I am thinking of having the audio go out over the HDMI to my monitor. Any beginner program will help. I can do the research on the individual commands after seeing the basics. If the program only sends to the audio output jack, that will be a good start also. (And yes, I have searched the site for "audio test program", and more).

I have looked [here on stack exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/891/audio-over-hdmi-hello-audio-bin-works-but-not-aplay)  , but there isn't shown a program to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further looking, I have answered my own question sufficiently.

I had been looking in Python but found my answers more related to Linux or Raspbian. The commands are related to using `alsa-utils` and were already on my disk.

The following commands allow me to hear audio on my headphones:

```
modprobe snd_bcm2835  # apparently addresses the processor audio section.
amixer cset numid=1 90%  # sets volume
aplay chime.wav  # my file chime.wav and heard through the audio headphone jack on Pi
```

Comment: btw, `amixer cset numid=3 2` will enroute you audio to the HDMI instead the analog ;)