# Sound click at the start and ending while playing audio file

Tags: audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get better Audio quality from audio jack output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3626/how-to-get-better-audio-quality-from-audio-jack-output)

My headphones are connected through the audio 3.5mm jack. When I want to play audio file (vlc/omxplayer) I hear a bothering click/crrrr before playing starts. Is there some way how could I fix this? Power source? Is it normal behaviour of the analog output on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Hi there. This is common behavior caused by an issue with the Broadcom firmware. You can see an existing answer [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3626/40).

Comment: Is it also present while using USB audio adapter?

Comment: That's something I've not tried... Might be worth a go though.