# Setting the default audio output to jack

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, audio

I have a Raspberry Pi with PiPlay and I'm trying to set the default audio output to analogic, but It doesn't work. I tried to change the audio settings in raspi-config but It only works on the current session. Thanks!

**SOLVED**
I edited the `/home/pi/piamame/config/piplay-sound.state` because I found It was a problem when changing from text mode to graphic mode and I changed from this:

```
control.3 {
    iface MIXER
    name 'PCM Playback Route'
    value 2
    comment {
        access 'read write'
        type INTEGER
        count 1
        range '0 - 2'
    }
}
```

to this:

```
control.3 {
    iface MIXER
    name 'PCM Playback Route'
    value 1
    comment {
        access 'read write'
        type INTEGER
        count 1
        range '0 - 2'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [How to make Raspberry use HDMI audio as default system output?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4289/how-to-make-raspberry-use-hdmi-audio-as-default-system-output?rq=1), all you need to do is:

```
sudo amixer cset numid=3 1
```

To test your audio, you can run:

```
cd /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_audio
make
./hello_audio.bin
```

NOTE: You will only need to run the make command on the first time.

Comment: That also works only in the current session, but thanks