# Raspberry Pi Sound Issues

Tags: audio, audio-playback

I saw [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-my-audio-sound-output-not-working/45#45) answer for configuring enabling and being able to use audio but was unsuccessful. I want to have audio to my headphones which are plugged into the 3.5mm jack. I have tried:

- Forcing audio to the headphone Jack
- Making sure I have alsa-utils installed(I asume I do because `aplay` does not give errors; in fact it says it is playing the file I give it!)
- I ran `modprobe snd_bcm2835`
- I made sure ALSA was starting when the Pi boots

All I hear is sort of white noise coming out of the jack regardless of whether `aplay` is running or not. I also made sure that it was a .wav file with these codecs: 22050khz, 16bit, mono, PCM Little Endian if that matters. But regardless of what wav or mp3 I use it does not work. The only noise I can get to work is the sine wave in the hello_world examples folder but with lots of noise. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are on Raspbian and `service pulseaudio status` says it is running, try, `sudo service pulseaudio stop` and see if that helps.  You might also have a look at `alsamixer` -- on the pi it is just one "PCM"  volume; you can turn it up and down w/ `+` and `-`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that and it returned something to the effect of "service unrecognized"! Does that mean I have to install pulseaudio? Do I need that to get audio working? I don't have a problem with the volume it just doesn't work it all.

Comment: If at all possible I would like to have sound without pulseaudio. Should my sound have worked on a new version of Raspbian or do you always have to fix it? I have seen a couple tutorials about it but wasn't able to get them to work.

Comment: No you do not have to use pulseaudio and unless you need it for some particular purpose which it provides (e.g. multiplexing), then I recommend not using it.  Beware though that some apps (e.g. `mpg123`) can be built with multiple backends (for pulse and alsa) and may default to pulse.  I don't think `aplay` is like that (but I don't think aplay does anything but PCM, i.e., `.wav` but not `.mp3`).  Your test sounds fine to me, although you might have a look at the various parameters (`man aplay`) to see if setting those manually helps.

Comment: After running `echo 'snd_bcm2835' >> /etc/modules` I was able to get omxplayer to play the wav files and mp3s. I didn't know what it meant put it worked! I haven't tried aplay again yet. Will update when I do.

Comment: Some things the kernel is able to detect at boot and load a driver itself, but the pi's sound is not one.  `/etc/modules` is a list of things that it will load regardless.  By default I think Raspbian *does* include `snd_bcm2835` in there, and `modprobe snd_bcm2835` should load it...so who knows.  You can always double check w/ `lsmod`, which lists loaded modules.