# How to enable sound on Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu 16

Tags: pi-3, audio, ubuntu

How do enable sound on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu 16?

I've tried the solutions outlined for Pi2, like [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-my-audio-sound-output-not-working), but nothing seems to work.

Running `sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` gives me the output:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
aplay: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Running `aplay -l` lists no devices.

Running `uname -a` shows:

```
Linux localhost 4.4.23-v7+ #913 SMP Tue Oct 4 14:16:19 BST 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5):

After digging around in my `/boot/config.txt`, I found the solution was to simply add the line `dtparam=audio=on`.

Comment: I had the same set up and problem and this solution _almost_ worked. After changing `config.txt` the sound card modules and all the alsa tools worked well. I now have the problem of hearing nothing but an audible "dead air" sound when I play a audio file to the analog output. Have you experienced something similar?

Answer (score 5):

## On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

On [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi), the file to be edited is `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`
Simply add `dtparam=audio=on`

Here is a one-liner that does exactly that:

```
$ echo 'dtparam=audio=on' |sudo tee -a /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt
```

Comment: Warning - this command will overwrite whatever is in your `/boot/firmware/config.txt`. That file acutally says: `Please DO NOT modify this file; if you need to modify the boot config, the "usercfg.txt"`
So this would be more appropriate and will append, not overwrite target file: `echo 'dtparam=audio=on' |sudo tee -a /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`

Comment: Yep, this will certainly screw up the bootloader

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Ubuntu 18.04.2

Hope this helps someone - I kept getting that long list of errors noted on this thread, I added this line to `/boot/firmware/config`:

```
dtparam=audio=on
```

rebooted and I can now generate a sound with

```
play -n synth 0.2 sin 440
```

I installed sox and alsa-utils and did this:

```
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
```

No idea what that did so I don't know if it was needed.