# Raspberry Pi 3 Sound Not Working With HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, retropie

The sound simply doesn't work, I'm using HDMI on a large flat-screen TV. Earlier today I had it working with HDMI on a smaller TV that is not a flat-screen. I have heard that it may have something to do with the resolution.

Any ideas?

Thanks. :D

Comment: Note that I'm running RetroPie; if it makes a difference. Thanks! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my audio (sound) output not working?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-my-audio-sound-output-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Open raspi-config by typing `sudo raspi-config` into the terminal.
Select option number 7 `Advanced Options` by moving the red bar with the arrow keys, and press `Enter`.
Select option A4 `Audio`, and press `Enter`.
Select option 2, and press `Enter` once more. It should now output audio to HDMI.

Comment: Did that, but when I try to leave the configuration menu I get stuck in a command prompt at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I don't know much about RetroPie, but try entering `exit`. If that doesn't work, try entering `sudo reboot`, and enter your password, it should reboot.

Comment: write "emulationstation" to run the emulator