# Pi zero - USB headset doesn't work?

Tags: pi-zero, audio-playback

I am trying to get audio output to a USB headset that is plugged into my pi zero. The headset can be seen and selected in the audio GUI and seen using aplay -l. However, there is still no sound output. Do I require a soundcard or similar device?
Thanks

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-my-audio-sound-output-not-working Check out the help from this thread.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange Network. You have got the volume turned up and the output is not marked as "muted" right? 8-) I see on my RPi I have the following that can control the sound levels: {command line UI}: `alsamixer`, `pimixer`; {GUI}: `alsamixergui`; {command line, direct get/set properties}: `amixer`.  I'd give __alsamixer__ a shot first of all...!

Comment: Hi did you manage to make it work after all? because Im thinking about using micro usb headset with my pi Zero as well.

Comment: @NouranS.Ahmad Hi. Yes, the headset did work. It happened to be an issue with the USB hub that I was using. Once I plugged the headset into a specific port on the hub it worked fine. Since you don't need a hub for a micro USB headset I don't see why you would have issues. Best of luck.

Comment: Just to point out something the micro usb headset didnt work, I tried more than one brand as well, so I ended up using a bluetooth headset.