# Raspberry pi 3 audio issue

Tags: audio, audio-playback, games

I am having trouble with my Raspberry Pi audio. I have the same problem with two different Pis, using two different TVs, two different HDMI cables, and one set of analogue speakers. To test sound, I have been using the pocket minecraft app that comes installed with the OS which I am hoping is a viable test. I have also been switching between HDMI and analogue audio outputs when the settings have been changed accordingly (I hope).

I get no sound from either of my Pis. I have researched and tried the common solutions for this problem and all except one failed me and the one that didn't will only play one audio file. I have tried following the steps listed in the accepted answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-my-audio-sound-output-not-working).

Specifically, changing the *config.txt* to uncomment `hdmi_drive=2` does not get me sound. Neither does changing the config file raspi-config nor using the relevant command `sudo amixer -c 0 cset numid=3`  with n=2.

What did work was the following three commands:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

this audio file played just fine. I get no sound from any other source on either Pi. Please help.

Comment: You should not mix your question and answer. Please edit your question and post the relevant part as an answer.

Comment: Please accept one answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Go to the terminal and type

`sudo raspi-config`

This will bring you to the raspian config. Go to 7, advanced options, go to A4 audio and change it to the speakers and headphones you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To have a correct answer, here the [solution posted in the question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/revisions/75034/3):

> I am going to post this even though I just answered my own question while gathering facts to make this post. I am doing this to hopefully help someone who runs into the same situation so that they don't waste hours of their life too.
>
> The games that come on the Raspberry Pi do not have audio >:( and do not tell you this at any point that I noticed. Both Pis work fine. Found this out by trying out a YouTube video as a different source just in case. So long 2hrs of my life. At least I learned something :|