# Retropie boots to 640x480 resolution over HDMI

Tags: pi-3, retropie

I flashed the latest Retropie image (4.4) and it boots with a resolution of 640x480  when connected over HDMI to my 4k TV.

I used the correct Retropie image for my Pi 3. I confirmed the screen resolution using `tvservice -s`.

How can I get it to run at 1080p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force a resolution by using `raspi-config` as follows:

1. `sudo raspi-config`
2. Select `Advanced Options`
3. Select `Resolution`
4. Select `DMT Mode 82 1920x1080 60Hz 16:9`

You can also do this manually by editing `/boot/config.txt` and uncommenting and changing the following lines:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
hdmi_drive=2
```

Comment: or `hdmi_group=1` `hdmi_mode=16`

Comment: With `hdmi_group=1` you use CEA. I experienced colour issues when using CEA on my TV, others may not.

Comment: fair enough - I read somewhere (though I can't find it, and it seems to be contradicted in official RPi docs) that using DMT, i.e. hdmi_group 2, will disable audio through HDMI

Comment: It might have for me, I thought it was an unrelated issue. If you follow this answer and don't have sound then do this: [Why is my audio (sound) output not working?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-my-audio-sound-output-not-working)